# Why is my dropper not dropping the MeshPart?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to create a dropper for my tycoon using a MeshPart however the part will not spawn in despite me trying all of what I think I could be doing. Any help is appreciated.

```lua
local dropper = script.Parent

local dropZone = dropper.DropZone

meshDrop = true

meshID = "rbxassetid://4863283216"  
textureID = "rbxassetid://4863283262"

while true do

    if dropper.Running.Value then

        wait(2)

        local drop = Instance.new('MeshPart')
        drop.CFrame = script.Parent.DropZone.CFrame - Vector3.new(0,5,0)
        drop.FormFactor = "Custom"
        drop.BrickColor = BrickColor.new('Gold')
        drop.Shape = Enum.PartType.Cylinder
        drop.Material = Enum.Material.Plastic
        drop.Size = Vector3.new(1,1,1)
        drop.Parent = game.Workspace
        if meshDrop == true then
            local m = Instance.new("SpecialMesh",drop)
            m.MeshId = meshID
            m.TextureId = textureID
        end

    end

end
```

I have tried basically every way I could think to do this. I even tried just adding the mesh to a regular Part and it still will not do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `while true` loop is causing the script to time out if the dropper is not enabled, because you are bypassing the `wait(2)` with the if then statement just before it, so if the dropper is not on, the script will time out. Replace `while true` with `while wait(2)` and remove the `wait(2)` from inside of the if then statement